# UIImage screen size condition weird behaviour

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uiimageview

So I need to differentiate the screen size (3.4 or 4 inch) devices in order to select the right image to display.

Here is what I did:  -- from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12733288/3322022)

```
#define IS_PHONEPOD5() ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0f && [UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.f && UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)

if(IS_PHONEPOD5()) {
    self.tutorialImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tutorialOverlay-568h@2x.png"];
} else {
    self.tutorialImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tutorialOverlay.png"];
}
```

Regardless of the screen size the image view always contains the larger image and extends off the screen (on the 3.5")

Am I doing something wrong, I have tried a few other things and it has always done the same thing.

EDIT: Even if I don't ever select the larger image it still is the one on screen at runtime:

```
        self.tutorialImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tutorialOverlay.png"];
```

It is still the larger image?

Comment: check your image resolution 4 inch is 640x1136 and 3.5 inch is 640x960

Comment: Else post your screen shot

Comment: may be your UIImageView size in increased by autoresizing in iOS 7.0 . check your UIIMageview size and compare after the running app

Comment: did you use autolayout

Comment: which os you have to test either it is iOS 6 or iOS 7

Comment: self.navigationcontroller.navigationbar.translucent = NO; use in your viewdidload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked UIViewContentMode of UIImageView? Try it by setting UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit and check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

don't use @2x in your image string. because every retina device will automatically take care of that.

use should save your image text like image@2x.png but i must use only without @2x extention. use properly like `[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];` this is for 3.5 inch.

How to use 4 inch screen use extention with -568h. Eg:

image-568h@2x.png. use like `[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-568h.png"];`

```
self.tutorialImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tutorialOverlay-568h.png"];
```

[image]
more detail

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html

Edited:

```
self.navigationcontroller.navigationbar.translucent = NO;
```

Comment: post your screen shot it is easily find the solution